# What does regex [*\f]+ mean?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, org-mode

In the org-mode the **outline-regexp** variable is set to `"[*\f]+"`.

I am not able to figure out what it stands for, [referred this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html#Syntax-of-Regexps) without success.

Edit:- **[*\f]+** changed to `"[*\f]+"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The default value matches asterisks and page breaks:
>    "[*\f]+"

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode#toc2

Answer (score 11):

`\f` stands for form feed, which is a special character used to instruct the printer to start a new page.

`[*\f]+` Then means any sequence entirely composed of * and form feed, arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Regexp Special` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
Note also that the usual regexp special characters are not special
inside a character alternative.  A completely different set of
characters is special inside character alternatives: `]', `-' and `^'.
```

So `[*\f]+` matches any sequence which is at least one character long, and contains (only) any number and combination of asterisks, backslashes, and the letter 'f'.

**EDIT:**

Ah, you actually meant `"[*\f]"`, did you? That's not the same thing as the regexp `[*\f]` (as the latter would be represented in string read syntax as `"[*\\f]"`).

Make sure you quote appropriately.

If you did mean `"[*\f]"` then the `\f` is indeed a form-feed, as indicated by the other answers.